# How to draw at top left of metaFile

Tags: c#, gdi+

I draw a simple Line in my MetaFile as:

```
  var g = CreateGraphics(); 
        var img = new Metafile(path, g.GetHdc()); 
        var ig = Graphics.FromImage(img);

ig.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), 0, 0, 300, 0);
```

and affter that, i try to save this metaFile as a png pcture like this:

```
var target = new Bitmap(200, 100);
var g2 = Graphics.FromImage(target);
g2.DrawImage(source,0,0);// source is my MetaFile
```

But the Line is not on the TOP LEFT of image :(
Why and how to do that?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks you,i found my solotion here is:

```
var img = new Metafile(path, g.GetHdc(), new Rectangle(0, 0, 101, 101), MetafileFrameUnit.Pixel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disposing the Graphics class you are using on your code before saving it to an image:

```
 using( Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage( metafile ) )
 {
     graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), 0, 0, 300, 0);
 } // right here in this point, the 'using' keyword launches graphics.Dispose(),
   // which is very importante when using graphics
```

Comment: Don't forget to use the same construction on your `g2` variable. Since it is also an GDI objects it needs to be disposed correctly.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, But my question here is about the coordinates in metafile :(

Comment: @LâmÁnh while drawing on Metafiles, the `PhisicalDimension` is given in millimeters. After you call the `graphics.Dispose()`, graphics flush all the drawings and should calculate correctly the coordinates. Check the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.physicaldimension(v=vs.110).aspx).